# Cpanel, User Cron jobs not appearing in cron log

Tags: php, apache, cron, cpanel

We recently did a large server migration, and for some reason cron isn't working as expected on the new system. Some cron scripts are running as normal but others don't seem to be executing at all.

If I look at the old server and tail the cron log /var/log/cron, I can see cron scripts executed as they should.

On the new server, none of the user cron execution shows up in the log. I can see general cron messages for user accounts, and I can see ROOT crons running, but no information on user crons other than general messages such as LIST, REPLACE, etc.

I've checked permissions on the files being executed. Some of the scripts log to files or send emails, so I know that some are running and some aren't. I've also verified the cron jobs are located in /var/spool/cron.

Most of these are php scripts, and the only change we made on this server vs. the other one is running apache using mpm-itk. This shouldn't be the problem though since file permissions weren't changed and shell is running php cli.

Would be a lot of help if I could verify the scripts are being executed. No errors in apache or other logs that I can find. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: are these cronjobs being controlled through cPanel or Linux? i understand that in Linux most cron scripts go into their appropriate folders. If something like cron that's being controlled through cPanel that control should be on cPanel side.

Comment: Just through cpanel under the cron section of the web interface. The execution should still hit the normal cron log, at least it is in 5 other cpanel servers I have access to.